# Having trouble to test IAP in iOS using flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to test my IAP subscriptions and whenever my app query the products using the product IDs, the query returns an empty result. I'm developing my app using flutter and I'm using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) API to do all my IAP translations for both Android and iOS. It works perfectly in Android, but when I try to test it in iOS it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
void _loadItems() async {
    final bool available = await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.isAvailable();
    if (!available) {
      print('Qyou Error: no connection to the store');
    }else{
      final ProductDetailsResponse response = await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.queryProductDetails(_kIds);
      if (response.notFoundIDs.isNotEmpty) {
        print('error not found IDs: ${response.notFoundIDs}');
      }
      products = response.productDetails;
      products.forEach((element) => print(element.price));
    }
  }
```

Here's my IAP in App Store Connect:
[image]

Comment: status should be Ready to Submit.